# Invalid JSON primitive as javascript parameter

Tags: c#, json

I am having this error. I always having problem with this quotes :(

```
<a class="btn-xs btn-info" title="Login As User" onclick="genericAjax("/Admin/LoginAsUser.aspx/LoginAs",{"UserUId":"854c46fc-6e50-4574-a103-16e16f24bf38"})" href="#">Login</a>

function genericAjax(url, data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { }
    });
}


    [WebMethod]
    public static object LoginAs(string UserUId)
    {
        //somecode
    }
```

Button Creator Javascript

```
 var param = '{';
                    for (t in CustomButtonJson[i].param)
                        param += '"' + CustomButtonJson[i].param[t]["Key"] + '":"' + rowData[CustomButtonJson[i].param[t]["Value"]] + '",';

                    param = param.substring(0, param.length - 1) + '}';

                    var ajax = 'genericAjax("' + CustomButtonJson[i].url + '/' + CustomButtonJson[i].ajaxMethod + '",' + param + ')';


                    button += 
                        "<a class='btn-xs btn-info' href='#' onclick=" + ajax + " " +
                            "title='" + CustomButtonJson[i].title + "'>" + CustomButtonJson[i].name + "</a>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <a class="btn-xs btn-info" title="Login As User" id="btnLogin" href="#">Login</a>
        <a class="btn-xs btn-info" title="Login As User" onclick="genericAjax('/Default.aspx/LoginAs', '{&quot;UserUId&quot;:&quot;bbbb&quot;}')" href="#">Login</a>

    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnLogin").click(function () {
                genericAjax('/Default.aspx/LoginAs', '{"UserUId":"aaaa"}');
            });
        });
        function genericAjax(url, data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) { alert(data.d); }
            });
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
onclick='genericAjax("/Admin/LoginAsUser.aspx/LoginAs",{"UserUId":"854c46fc-6e50-4574-a103-16e16f24bf38"})'
```

You're using double quotes for surrounding the `onclick` event, but also to pass in parameters to `genericAjax` so there's no way for JS to distinguish between the two uses here.

Instead, wrap the whole thing with a different set of characters (single quotes) (I think you also have the option to escape the quotes here but this is the simplest solution I can see).

Funnily enough - the colouring of StackOverflow's code snippets here illustrate perfectly what I'm explaining. Compare the colours to my proposed solution above to the following (yours) and you can see what's happening:

```
onclick="genericAjax("/Admin/LoginAsUser.aspx/LoginAs",{"UserUId":"854c46fc-6e50-4574-a103-16e16f24bf38"})"
```

Comment: I couldn't make your style, whenever I use ' browser truns that to " ; I paste my button creator script to question too.

Comment: still getting same error this is output ; onclick="genericAjax('/Admin/LoginAsUser.aspx/LoginAs',{"UserUId":"854c46fc-6e50-4574-a103-16e16f24bf38"})"